# jquery id selector doesn't work in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I have the following selector:

```
$('#terminal-template').text()
```

and following jsp page fragment inside the body :

```
<script type="text/template" id="terminal-template">
    <li data-terminal-id="{{ id }}" class="{{ clazz2 }}">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="terminal" class="{{ clazz }}" data-terminal-id="{{ id }}" />
            <a href="#" title="" class="image"><img
                    src="getSmallThumbnail/{{imageId}}"
                    alt=""/></a>

            <h3>{{ name }}
                <small>{{ place }}</small>
            </h3>

            <p class="count">Проходимость: <span>{{ count }}</span> чел./час</p>

            <p class="count">Стоимость: <span>{{ amount }}</span> руб./час</p>

            <p class="count">Количество свободных слотов: <span>{{ numberOfEmptyCase }}</span> </p>
        </label>
    </li>
</script>
```

In IE  `$('#terminal-template').text()` it returns empty (`""`)

but in chrome - it works properly and returns

```
"
    <li data-terminal-id="{{ id }}" class="{{ clazz2 }}">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="terminal" class="{{ clazz }}" data-terminal-id="{{ id }}" />
            <a href="#" title="" class="image"><img
                    src="getSmallThumbnail/{{imageId}}"
                    alt=""/></a>

            <h3>{{ name }}
                <small>{{ place }}</small>
            </h3>

            <p class="count">Проходимость: <span>{{ count }}</span> чел./час</p>

            <p class="count">Стоимость: <span>{{ amount }}</span> руб./час</p>

            <p class="count">Количество свободных слотов: <span>{{ numberOfEmptyCase }}</span> </p>
        </label>
    </li>
"
```

Comment: Did you try using `.html()`? `.text()` may be failing with `script` tags in IE8.

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: jquery version 1.8.2

Comment: ok. the version seems to be fine. i tried this and was able to make it work on IE8 `var templateVal = $('#terminal-template').clone();
    console.log(templateVal.html());` can you try this and tell me if it works for you?

Comment: Sushil,  manji already answered right

Comment: yeah but I am using `clone()`

Comment: did you try it using `clone()`??

Answer (score 0):

When fetching HTML from inside a template, stored inside a dummy script block, you should always use `.html()`, not `text()`.

e.g. this will work on all browsers:

```
var html = $('#terminal-template').html();
```

*I am actually surprised that `text()` returns anything on any browser, but I guess Google though that might be useful. Technically script content is "text", but that was not standardised across all browsers so is best avoided. `html()` is guaranteed to return the `innerHTML` property so will always work on all browsers*